# Xpath get child that does not contain class

Tags: xpath

I have a xml like this and am trying to select the groupIdentifier element without the display:none child (would like to use the css "identifier" along with it) to finally select the input. Have been at this for hours and would like to call the xpath gods to help me out.

```
<div class="groupIdentifier">
    <div>
        <input class="inputClassIdentifier">
    </div>
    <div>
      ...
        <div>
            <div class="something">
                ... some more elements
            </div>
            <div class="identifier hidden" style="display: none">
                ... some more elements
            </div>
            <div class="something">
                ... some more elements
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="groupIdentifier">
    <div>
        <input class="inputClassIdentifier">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="something">
                ... some more elements
            </div>
            <div class="identifier ">
                ... some more elements
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

edit:
I have 
`//div[contains(@class, 'identifier') and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]` which basically selects the identifier div of the second section.
What I need now is to select the input with class `inputClassIdentifier` within its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your xpath.

```
//div[@class='groupIdentifier' and div/div/div[not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]]
```

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity, we dont know the div depth is 3

Answer (score 0):

I got it using `descendant` axis

```
//div[@data-testid='groupIdentifier' and descendant::div[contains(@class, 'identifier') and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]]//input[@name='inputClassIdentifier']
```